# How to trunc double precision number without rounding?

Tags: postgresql

I have `'9.999999999'::double precision` number and I want to convert it to `decimal(8,2)` without any rounding. The result I am expecting is `9.99`. So far I tried:

```
select trunc('9.999'::double precision::numeric(8,3), 2)
```

and it works but I have to know number of precision digits for double precision value because if there will be more `9` then `::numeric(8,3)` will automatically round it to `10.000`.

What I can do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply do the following?

```
SELECT trunc(num, 2) 
 FROM (VALUES (         9.999999                  ), 
              (         9.999999999999999999999999), 
              (9999999999.999999999999999999999999)
      ) t(num);

/*
     trunc     
───────────────
          9.99
          9.99
 9999999999.99
*/
```

This way you just truncate it, without assuming anything about the digits.

**Notes:**

- it looks like you have numbers stored as text.  Avoid this, if you can.  If this is not the case, just don't explicitly cast anything.  If it is, then:
- It might not be obvious, but my example is using `numeric` - this is the type the parser interprets `9.99999`, for example:

```sql
SELECT pg_typeof(9.99999);
 pg_typeof 
───────────
 numeric
```

That is, use an unlimited `numeric` in your example.  This would accomodate all your digits.

- According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL):

  > The types decimal and numeric are equivalent.